# Spin Docker Containers to allow multiple user for code development

Tags: windows-10, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, winscp, docker-for-windows

I would like to know if it is possible to spin multiple docker containers in a single windows 10 pro host machine to allow multiple users to ssh in and work at the same time in isolated environment in each container.

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Docker for Windows installed 
Docker for Linux installed in Windows Subsystem Linux
Containers: To contain an Anaconda Environment build to run a python application.

Using Winscp (OpenSSH for Windows) to allow multiple user to ssh in to Windows 10 Pro.